# Replace JOIN with IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know if it can even be, but can I replace JOIN in the first code to IN?

```
select first_name, last_name, team_name
from player 
join team_info on team_info.team_id = player.team_id

--doesn't work
select first_name, last_name, team_name
from player
where team_name in (select team_name from team_info)
```

player table:

| player_id | first_name | last_name | team_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Harry | Kane | 2 |
| 2 | Matthiew | Batrop | 3 |
| 3 | Frayda | Varker | 4 |
| 4 | Kaleb | Briars | 1 |

team_info table:

| team_id | team_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tottenham HotSpurs |
| 2 | Manchester United |
| 3 | Manchester City |
| 4 | Arsenal |

Comment: Why do you want to change it? You really need to expand your question with sample data and desired results, showing which tables the columns come from.

Comment: @DaleK I can agree that it may indeed seem strange, but I will not be sad if there is no answer. I edited the question

Comment: You still haven't exlained why you want to change a working query to use a different technique?

Comment: I guess that there was no need to write the entire table here. As for why, to find out the possibilities of this operator. Edited again, must be correct

Comment: Did my answer provide you with helpful information?

Answer (score 2):

A short answer:

Yes, kind of, if you're willing to give up returning `team_name` in your query. You could use this:

```
select first_name, last_name, team_id
from player
where team_id in (select team_id from team_info)
```

I should probably note that this does no filtering at all, so you'll get all the players on all the teams for which you have information.

You could also do this, if you wanted:

```
select first_name, 
       last_name, 
       (select team_name 
          from team_info 
         where team_info.team_id = player.team_id) as team_name
from   player
```

A line or two of explanation: anything that appears in a `select` clause has to be either retrieved from a table in the `from` clause, or be calculated from something retrieved from a table in the `from` clause, be a subquery (as in example 2), or be a literal.

So if you want to use `team_info.team_name`, then you need to use `team_info` in your `from` clause, as you originally did, or put it in a subquery, as I did in example 2.

Some more explanation: `in` is used in `where` and `having` clauses: when you are *filtering* data. `join` is used to connect tables to each other in the `from` clause. They serve different purposes and are used in different parts of the query, so they aren't interchangeable.

So that's an answer. I do wonder, along with Dale, though, what your reason was for wanting to change a perfectly adequate query!